# Dealing with DateTime and Null values

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

1. I have variable called modifieddate of type DateTime, which can be set to null.
2. I fill in the variable using a datareader and set the value to nothing if the reader is empty
3. when I use the variable further down, the store procedure complaints that I am not providing the value. "Procedure or function 'tHistory_Insert' expects parameter '@modifieddate', which was not supplied"

Question: Any ideas on how to pass null values into the store procedure when the date in empty?

**Step 1**

```
Public modifieddate As Nullable(Of DateTime)
```

**Step 2**

```
If IsDBNull(dr("modifieddate")) = False Then

     modifieddate = DateTime.Parse(dr("modifieddate"))
Else

     modifieddate = Nothing
End If
```

**Step 3**

```
command.Parameters.Add("@modifieddate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = modifieddate
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: change stored procedure parameter to `@modifieddate datetime = null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's nothing, I think you have to pass the DBNull.Value.  Something like this:

```
If modifieddate Is Nothing then
  command.Parameters.Add(...).Value = DBNull.Value
Else
  command.Parameters.Add(...).Value = modifieddate
End If
```

Comment: And you don't need to use Nullable(Of DateTime), you can just use DateTime and test for Nothing or use Date.MinValue as your nothing.

Comment: @rs. I just tried it.  My stored procedure worked without setting the parameter with `= null` and I passed it the `DBNull.Value`.  Are you referring to the table itself?